# Libgdx create image thumbnail

Tags: java, android, libgdx

i'm planning to create a simple list on my game that contains stuffs.. here's my idea.. it would looked like this

[image]

on the left side of the list, there are 3 images (look at the red arrow mark lol), that will be put on the list

the problem is, the size of these images are different..so is there any solution to create something like an image thumbnail in LibGdx so that the list will look nice like this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I might be miss understanding you but can't you just draw the original in the size you want?

```
Texture t = new Texture("someImage");

//Now let's say those list rows are 100 units tall and you want some room on the edges.
float height = 80;

//Calculate width taking aspect ratio in consideration
float width = height * ((float)t.width / (float)t.height);
```

Now you can draw the image using those sizes. Each image will have a height of 80 and scale correctly.

If you want all the images have the same size you just draw it using the size you want. But then images gets stretched obviously. A third option would be the create your thumbnails manually.

Comment: Okay, i'll try your advice :)
Btw, is that any difference if i use Image instead of Texture for this?

Comment: @thekucays No it isn't as long as you use the correct ratio's to calculate the width in the last line.

Comment: @thekucays but if you use image inside something like a `Table` you have to do `table.add(image).width(width).height(height);` Then correct it by using padding, in above case `.pad(10)` would work.

Comment: Okay, thanks! And you're right, i'm planning to put these inside a Table :)